# Reusing test methods in other .JS files in Cypress.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cypress

Below are my login.js and client creation.js file where I created to test my application.

login.js executes in the test runner and works correctly, but I want to use the

```
it("Successful Login", function () {

    cy.visit('/login')
    cy.get('#username').type('admin')
    cy.get('#password').type('Qwerty@123')
    cy.get('.btn').click()

})
```

method each time test cases being executed in clientCreation.js.

**what is the best way to perform it? without putting it to the foreach of clientCreation.js file**

Login.js

```
    describe("Login to the system", function () {

    it("Successful Login", function () {

        cy.visit('/login')
        cy.get('#username').type('admin')
        cy.get('#password').type('Qwerty@123')
        cy.get('.btn').click()

    })

    it("Unsuccessful login", function () {

        cy.visit('/login')
        cy.get('#username').type('invalid')
        cy.get('#password').type('Invalid')
        cy.get('.btn').click()

    })
})
```

---

clientCreation.js

````
```
beforeEach(() => {
   
})

describe('Client Creation Test Suite', function () {


    it('Check the user can create a client', function () {

      //test code

    })


    it('Check the client creation validation', function () {

       //test code
    })


})
````

I will also attach the project structure for your reference.[image]

Comment: Do you want to make the login process reusable? as using it in clientCreation.js ?

Comment: @HasipTimurtas yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cypress [Custom Commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax) to write reusable commands.

Go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and write your reusable commands like:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('loginSuccess', (username, password) => {
   cy.get('#username').type(username)
   cy.get('#password').type(password)
   cy.get('.btn').click()
})

Cypress.Commands.add('loginFail', (username, password) => {
   cy.get('#username').type(username)
   cy.get('#password').type(password)
   cy.get('.btn').click()
})
```

And then you can use this in any tests like for example in `clientCreation.js` -

```
describe('Client Creation Test Suite', function() {
   beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit('/login')
   })
   it('Check the user can create a client', function() {
      //test code
      cy.loginSuccess('admin', 'Qwerty@123')
   })
   it('Check the client creation validation', function() {
      //test code
      cy.loginFail('invalid', 'invalid')
   })
})
```

Comment: Seems your solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

I do this way and it is useful. create a file login. It will be a function with parameters: cy, username and password.

```
module.exports = function (cy, username, pass){
  cy.visit('/login')
  cy.get('#username').type(username)
  cy.get('#password').type(pass)
  cy.get('.btn').click()
}
```

and call it in the test file you want to run which is in clientCreation.js

```
const login = require('./login');  // path to login.js

beforeEach(() => {
   
})

describe('Client Creation Test Suite', function () {

    it('Check the user can create a client', function () {
      login(cy, "admin", "12345");

      //test code

    })


    it('Check the client creation validation', function () {

       //test code
    })
})
```

Comment: this way not work, i can not create a utils.js and put inside my reusable functions, and import inside mys tests and works. allways has the error that it's waiting a command.